# ORDER BY field from a comma separated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order a query based on the comma separated result of another query

```
SELECT t.field1, t.field2 /*, ...*/
FROM table t
/* ... */
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = t.field1) 
        THEN FIELD(t.field2, (SELECT field_order FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = t.field1))
        ELSE FIELD(t.field2, (SELECT field_order FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = 0))
    END
```

The important part of the query is this

```
FIELD(t.field2, (SELECT field_order FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = t.field1))
```

So basically, the subquery returns a comma separated string `1,2,3,7,9,4,10`, and I want to order by those fields first.

I know we can do for example `ORDER BY FIELD(t.field,2,1,2,3)`, but how can we use a subquery that returns a string, to fill the order field?

Comment: dynamic sql is needed

Comment: @Hogan hi! Thank you for your comment. I'm no sql expert, could you link me to some documentation please? I'll greatly appreciate it!

Comment: did you do a google search on dynamic sql mysql?

Comment: @BillKarwin  Find in set returns the index of an item in a list.  How does that help to specify the field name to an order by clause?

Comment: @Hogan I suppose you mean by using procedures? I've never used any before, I'll try to take a look at how it could be accomplished. Thank you :)

Comment: yeah mysql only supports dynamic sql in a stored procedure

Comment: so just to be clear -- does the comma separated list specify the order or specify the fields to sort by.  Bills answer is using the list to specify the order (that is the first item in the list is the id of the first item returned)  where I thought the first item is the list was the column name you want to sort on.  My case is the most common (since you are often passed a list of columns to sort on).  It is rare you passed a list of the id numbers in order.

Comment: @Hogan in my case it is indeed a list of the id numbers to order upon. Maybe my logic in itself is bad.

Comment: Not really wrong -- just unusual.  Bill's answer should work just fine.  But there are better ways to do this.   I'd recommend storing the ordering information in a table so that you can just join to it to get your order (and with an inner join filter out items you don't have.)  This would be the more typical approach.  You could also convert those lists to a table first and then join -- which would probably be faster -- depending on a number of things (like the size of your lists)

Comment: @Hogan I could've created a table with a simple join, but the logic behind this field is more complex, I can't join directly. If the answer below works, it'd be enough, I think. I'll also try to benchmark and see if the performance is really poorer, I'll think of another way to create the table. Thank you for your comments, really appreciate it! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no neeed for dynamic sql.

you can doit with `FIND_IN_SET`

But still this is slower as when you had a normalized Structure.

and fyi you should read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

A simplifieed version of your query to demonstarte that it works

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (Sortder varchar(100), id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('1,2,3,4',0),('4,3,2,1',1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe t2 (f1 int, val varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t2
> ORDER BY
> CASE WHEN  4 = 5
> THEN  find_in_set( f1, (SELECT Sortder FROM t1 WHERE id = 0) )
> ELSE find_in_set( f1, (SELECT Sortder FROM t1 WHERE id = 1) )
> END
> ```
>
> ```
> f1 | val
> -: | :--
>  4 | d  
>  3 | c  
>  2 | b  
>  1 | a
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t2
> ORDER BY
> CASE WHEN  5 = 5
> THEN  find_in_set( f1, (SELECT Sortder FROM t1 WHERE id = 0) )
> ELSE find_in_set( f1, (SELECT Sortder FROM t1 WHERE id = 1) )
> END
> ```
>
> ```
> f1 | val
> -: | :--
>  1 | a  
>  2 | b  
>  3 | c  
>  4 | d
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbb8e0c840de837042ea8a86abd68f42)*

Answer (score 1):

The function that you can use to locate a value in a comma separated list of values is [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

You don't need the `CASE` expression and `EXISTS`:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(
           t.field2,
           COALESCE(
             (SELECT field_order FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = t.field1),
             (SELECT field_order FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = 0)
           )
         )
```

When there is no row in `table1` satisfying the condition of the 1st subquery:

```
SELECT field_order FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = t.field1
```

then its result is `null` in which case `COALESCE()` will return the result of the 2nd subquery:

```
SELECT field_order FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.field1sub = 0
```

Another way to write the `ORDER BY` clause would be:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(
           t.field2,
           (
             SELECT field_order 
             FROM table1 t1 
             WHERE t1.field1sub IN (t.field1, 0) 
             ORDER BY t1.field1sub = 0 LIMIT 1
           )
         )
```

In this case, the subquery:

```
SELECT field_order 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE t1.field1sub IN (t.field1, 0) 
ORDER BY t1.field1sub = 0 LIMIT 1
```

returns the row with `t1.field1sub = t.field1` if it exists, but if it does not exist it returns the row with `t1.field1sub = 0`.